# Expo DownloadAsync don't download files which contains spaces in filename

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I have a problem with `DownloadAsync` when trying to download files from Firebase storage. If filename doesn't contain spaces it works fine and file is downloaded to app, but if it have a space in file name, then that file is ignored and not downloaded. Problem appears only in iOS, with Android I did't have this problem.

Also Firebase gives me a link for that file, so there is no problem with Firebase.

This is how my code looks:

```
await getDownloadURL(
   ref(
      storage,
      `/images/objects/${touristObject.id}/${file}`
   )
)
.then(async (url) => {
   const fileReference = 
      `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}images/objects/${touristObject.id}`

   await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
      fileReference,
      { intermediates: true }
   )
                                      
   await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      url,
      `${fileReference}/${file}`
   )
   .then((uri) => { resolve() })
   .catch((error) => {
      console.warn(error)
      resolve()
   })
})
.catch((error) => {
   console.warn(error)
   resolve()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) the file name:

```
encodeURI(fileName)
```

Note that do not encode `FileSystem.documentDirectory` itself because it is already encoded. Only encode the path or filename you append after it.